# h:commandLink causes JS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'adp' of null

Tags: jsf

I got below error

> jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'adp' of null

when i add `h:form` to use `h:commandLink`

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="View AMC" action="#{treeTableManagedBean.redirectPage()}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I don't know where this 'adp' come from?

Comment: Are you trying to access some java-script variable in your xhtml page ?

Comment: I dont have any java-script code in my xhtml page.

Comment: public String redirectPage()
   {
    System.out.println("inside redirectPage");
    flag = false;
    return "ViewAMC?faces-redirect=true";
    
   }

Comment: When i click this link, i only want to call this method.

Comment: Please add more code at least Minimal working code .

Comment: At first, i did with <a and call this method on action method. So whenever page is reload, keep calling this action method without clicking to this link

Comment: that's why I change with <h:commandLink

Comment: If i dont add h:form, still reloading in current page and cannot redirect to target page

Comment: So I add <h:form and i got this error

Comment: try to add .xhtml in redirect link ViewAMC.xhtml

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: cannot, still got this error.

Comment: Please share code like this no one will able to help you

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are putting this `h:form` within another `h:form.Nesting` of `h:form` is not allowed in HTML or JSF pages. Cross check again.

I faced this issue once. This was the reason I was getting above exception.

Comment: I had the same issue today. And I found nested h:form in my code. Removing nesting helped to fix.

Comment: @AlekseyTimohin
Yes I got same issue when I putted my h:commadLink in nested h:form

But If it is in single h:form then my action method is not getting called
Can you suggest me cause of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using h:commandButton instead, worked for me.

Comment: The problem isn't the button type but the form nested.